# How to enable/disable GPS Programatically in Android 4.4?

Tags: android, gps

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(intent);`
```

I use this code for Enable GPS but it give me error like this.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE from pid=1208, uid=10051
```

So anyone give me solution of that.

Comment: You cannot programmatically enable/disable GPS in android. You can ask the user to enable/disable it.

Answer (score 5):

you never do that. it was bug in API. you can now give settings to user for choose using below intent:

```
startActivity(context, new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: Use this code in Wallpaper Service so its not working in that to open activity.

Comment: Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS its package name?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void turnGPSOn()
     {
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
     intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
     this.ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);

     String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
     if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
     final Intent poke = new Intent();
     poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
     poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
     poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
     this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
     }
```